# Function in ng-repeat with track by causes Infinite $digest-loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Apparently I did not yet understand the mechanic behind `ng-repeat`, `$$hashKeys` and `track by`.

I am currently using AngularJS 1.6 in my project.

**The Problem:**

I got an array of complex objects which i want to use to render a list in my view. But to get the required result i need to modify (or map/enhance/change) these objects first:

```
const sourceArray = [{id: 1, name: 'Dave'}, {id:2, name: Steve}]

const persons = sourceArray.map((e) => ({enhancedName: e.name + e.id})) 

//Thus the content of persons is:
//[{enhancedName: 'Dave_1'}, {enhancedName: 'Steve_2'}]
```

Binding this to the view should be working like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="person in ctrl.getPersons()">
    {{person.enhancedName}}
</div>
```

However this obviously runs into a `$digest()`-loop, because `.map` returns new object-instances every time it is called. Since I bind this to ng-repeat via a function, it gets reevaluated in every `$digest`, the model does not stabilize and Angular keeps rerunning `$digest`-cycles because these objects are flagged as `$dirty`.

**Why i am confused**

Now this is not a new issue and there are several solutions for this:

In [an Angular-Issue from 2012](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/705) Igor Minar himself suggested to set the $$hashKey-Property manually to tell angular that the generated objects are the same. [This](http://jsfiddle.net/LE6Ay/1/) is his working fiddle, but since even this very trivial example still ran into a `$digest`-loop when i used it in my project, i tried upgrading the Angular-Version in the fiddle. For some reason [it crashes](http://jsfiddle.net/j79sfvhb/).

Okay... since Angular 1.3 we have `track by` which should essentially solve this exact problem. However both

```
<div ng-repeat="person in ctrl.getPersons() track by $index">
```

and

```
<div ng-repeat="person in ctrl.getPersons() track by person.enhancedName">
```

crash with a `$digest`-loop. I was under the impression that the `track by` statement should let angular believe it works with the same objects, but apparently this is not the case since it just keeps checking them for changes. To be honest, i have no idea how i can properly debug the cause of this.

**Question:**

Is it possible to use a filtered/ modified array as data-source for ng-repeat?

I do not want to store the modified array on my controller, because i need to update its data constantly and would then have to maintain and refresh it manually in the controller instead of relying on databinding.

Comment: A (by now deleted) answer asked for more details on the actual usecase: The `sourceArray` in my app is a lot more complex than in this example. Thus I would like to remove all data from it that is not needed by the view (for readability). In addition to that I need to map some information and businesslogic to other datatypes (i.e. "When this array has 10 or more entries, this toggle-button should be rendered as 'clicked'") To properly bind this with ng-model i would like to use `Object.defineProperty` with custom getter and setter methods which contain the according businesslogic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "[it crashes](https://jsfiddle.net/ro6e95d7/)" fiddle that you provided, did not produce an infinite digest for me. In fact: it did not even successfully bootstrap the Angular app (looks like bootstrapping cannot be done that way in latest Angular).

I [rewrote it](https://jsfiddle.net/8dr2ey0h/1/) to use an Angular bootstrap mechanism that I understood. It reproduces the crash, like you said.

I found a way to make it successfully [track by stringified JSON](https://jsfiddle.net/ro6e95d7/1/).

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular.min.js"></script>

<script>
angular.module('myApp',[])
.controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    angular.extend($scope, {
    stringify: function(x) { return JSON.stringify(x) },
    getList: function() {
      return [
        {name:'John', age:25},
        {name:'Mary', age:28}
      ];
    }
  });
}]);
</script>

<div ng-app="myApp">

<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
  I have {{getList().length}} friends. They are:
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="friend in getList() track by stringify(friend)">
      [{{$index + 1}}] {{friend.name}} who is {{friend.age}} years old.
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

</div>
```

i.e. we provide a tracking function, `stringify()`. There's probably an Angular builtin for that, too.

`track by $index` worked as well — contrary to your finding. I think JsFiddle ruined the experimentation slightly*

*The following is anecdotal. I believe that I experienced some problems with *JsFiddle itself*. For example: my `track by stringify()` example didn't work until I forked the Fiddle and tried the same code again in a new browsing context. I believe that as soon as I ever got *any* infinite digest: that JsFiddle would *always* infinite digest. It seemed like there was some statefulness that was lingering from previous runs. So, I would advise that *anything you saw fail in JsFiddle*, you try again *in a new JsFiddle*.

As for why your `$$hashKey` trick led to an infinite digest — I think Angular does not expect `$$hashKey` to be a function. So probably instead of invoking your function, it did a *reference comparison* of the function assigned to `$$hashKey`.

Since you assign to `$$hashKey` a *new instance* of the comparator each time you invoke `getList()`: the references could *never* be equal on subsequent digests, and so it would keep trying the digest forever.

**EDIT**: updated StackOverflow embed and JsFiddle to use HTTPS CDN (to avoid falling afoul of mixed content security).

Comment: Thanks a lot already :) For me your working example does not work yet though (tested in chrome and firefox). It still does not print any values in the view. I am currently testing if thats caused bythe issue with fiddle that you mentioned. As to your other thoughts: that track by $index works for you is both a relief (as i think it should work...) and bad news because it doesn't work for me and i have no clue what can be causing this. The `$$hashKey` trick was used by Igor Minar (AngularJS technical lead) in the example that i linked in my question and for some reason it was working for him...

Comment: even without navigating to the JsFiddle mirror: I find that in Firefox Nightly, if I click the "Run code snippet" on this StackOverflow post, it certainly prints values to the view (and no digest errors in console). So this further corroborates that JsFiddle may be at fault. As for Igor Minar's `$$hashKey` trick: it's entirely possible that Angular worked differently 5 years ago. You may find that having both `$$hashKey` _and_ `track by $index` doesn't make sense. Assuming that `track by …` provides a _strategy_ for populating `$$hashKey`, then providing both means they will fight each other.

Comment: @HW This code fails in Chrome/Chromium-based browsers for an unrelated reason: [Mixed Content security](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content) is preventing the app on a secure context (HTTPS) from loading the Angular library over HTTP. StackOverflow auto-redirects HTTP to HTTPS so you can't cross-check StackOverflow, but at least you can try visiting the JSFiddle [over HTTP](http://jsfiddle.net/ro6e95d7/). Alternatively, check this [updated JSFiddle over HTTP](http://jsfiddle.net/ro6e95d7/1/) where Angular is imported from a secure context. The code itself works!

Comment: JSON.Stringify is expensive and not the proper way to use a trackBy. Its probably happening cause the ng-repeat expression is a function. Meaning it evaluates it every digest cycle and creates a new array. See Francesco's answer I think he's on the right track.

Comment: any hash function that deterministically distinguishes each array element will suffice; I used stringify because that's what was used in the question's Fiddle. It's _fine_ to create a new array each digest cycle, because we track the _hashes of the elements_ in the array, not the array itself.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the watched expression `getPersons()` returns a **new** array, even with the same elements, the `$digest` cycle, which uses `===` comparison, cannot stop; regardless the `track by` expression, that comes into play for **rendering** nodes, after the [change detection](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#tracking-and-duplicates) of `ngRepeat`.

```js
(function() {
  angular
    .module('app', [])
    .controller('AppController', AppController)

  function AppController($interval) {
    // you may have more performant options here
    const hashFn = angular.toJson.bind(angular)
    // your mapping logic for presentation
    const mapFn = (e) => ({
      enhancedName: e.name + e.id
    })

    // initialization of data
    let sourceArray = [{
      id: 1,
      name: 'Dave'
    }, {
      id: 2,
      name: 'Steve'
    }]

    // initialization of "cache"
    let personList = sourceArray.map(mapFn),
        lastListHash = hashFn(sourceArray)

    Object.defineProperty(this, 'personList', {
      get: function() {
        const hash = hashFn(sourceArray)
        if (hash !== lastListHash) {
          personList = sourceArray.map(mapFn)
          lastListHash = hash
        }

        // you need to return **the same** array
        // if the source has not been updated
        // to make `$digest` cycle happy
        return personList
      }
    })

    // test of changes
    $interval(() => sourceArray.push({
      id: Date.now(),
      name: 'a'
    }), 1000)
  }
})()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">

  <div ng-controller="AppController as ctrl">
    There are {{ctrl.personList.length}} persons.
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="person in ctrl.personList track by $index">
        [{{$index + 1}}] {{ person.enhancedName }}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```